# App Groups - "unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the member center"

Tags: watchkit

In trying to add an app group (for an apple watch app that can share data beween the phone and watch) I always run into this problem, where the first step ("add the app groups entitlement to your entitlements file") gets checked, but the other 2 steps have red errors because of this "unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the member center" problem.

I've downloaded test projects where people show how to share data between the phone and watch, but they never work for me in the simulator (always gives nil data) whereas they do for other people - I believe it's because of this app group error I'm getting where only 1 of the 3 steps is ok. I don't have an iphone so I can't register one in the member center as it wants me to. And going to Build Settings -> Code Signing and manually selecting a provisioning profile (as is necessary when submitting iphone apps when you don't have an iphone, as I've done before) still doesn't solve these app group errors.

Has anyone without an iphone got an app group working properly with all 3 steps? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you already setup a simple app in the AppStore so it works?

Comment: I have submitted apps before, yes. This problem is unique to adding an app group in the Capabilities section.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it's not some basic user error. I guess that dealing with alpha-software like WatchKit will offer quite a couple more of those trap doors. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully this tutorial: http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/108082269360/sharing-data-between-apps-and-their-extenstions

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (after trying to get around it for a few hours) you definitely need an iphone registered in your developer profile in order to use app groups in the current xcode watchkit beta. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.